# Change error message for locked out user in PasswordRecovery control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, password-recovery

I use the ASP.NET PasswordRecovery control in combination with the standard membership provider. A locked out user gets the confusing error message

*We were unable to access your information. Please try again.*

I want to change this message, but find no way. The properties XXXFailureText especially GeneralFailureText contain over strings. There seems to be a hidden text used for this special kind of error I can't change using a property.

Comment: any code examples?? your asp code and the properties of the control??

Comment: You don’t want them. Believe me. A sub classed PasswordControl, dynamically created, custom membership provider derived from SqlMembershipProvider, no mark-up code. All is working fine. Just an error message I can’t change, because the control hasn’t the right property to change the error message for locked out users.

Comment: Well its kinda hard to troubleshoot something that seems simple but isnt being fixed by the simple solution... Which means the simple question is insufficient

Comment: I tried to rephrase the end. May be it is clearer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was causing me a headache too, until I tried this. I added code to the VerifyingUser event to set the UserNameFaileurText if the user was locked out and it worked great, that is the error message was exactly what I wanted it to be.

```
 protected void PasswordRecovery1_VerifyingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(PasswordRecovery1.UserName);
    if (membershipUser != null && membershipUser.IsLockedOut)
    {
        PasswordRecovery1.UserNameFailureText = string.Format("<span style='font-            size:larger'>Your account has been locked. Please contact<br/>your <a href='mailto:webmanager@aaa.co.uk?subject=Locked Account - {0}'>system administrator</a>.</span>", PasswordRecovery1.UserName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a custom membership provider? This error can be cause by a partially implemented membership provider.

You also need to check you web.config settings. make sure that something like this is set:

```
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
```

As well as check they your mailsettings/smtp section is setup properly with a 'from' email address.

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="noreply@mysite.com">
    <network host="mysite.smtp.server" port="25"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

or set the 'from' in `PasswordRecovery`

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery runat="server">
    <MailDefinition From="passwordrecovery@mysite.com">
    </MailDefinition>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

btw, your specified error message is the default `UserNameFailureText`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.usernamefailuretext.aspx

If all else fails, you could hijack the events and cancel them, then show your own error message. Specially the `UserLookupError` and the other *Error events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery_events.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but... The error is caused by a locked out user and that there is an error isn't my problem. It is the correct behaviour. The error message I can't modify is my problem - and sorry, but it isn't the default for UserNameFailureText. Handling UserLookupError is a last option for a workaround, but it is triggered before the password recovery. If I use it, I have to implement parts of the PasswordRecovery logic to change a error message.

Comment: At least that takes care of the usual suspects. I can't think of any other settings that can override it the way you want. It may be that it is the intended that way for membership to work. i.e User auth cannot be tried for a locked user. I think the best way is to plug in to the 'VerifyingUser' event and check if the a/c is locked. Then show whatever error message you need to show.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties window of the control there is a field for the text displayed that you can change
[image: PasswordRecoveryProperties]

Comment: I tried the three FailureText properties with no result. Do you mean them or anything else?

Comment: @dirk Did you rebuild the solution??? Also do you have a dev and production code where you might be only changing the code for developement and not on your live site??